# Quick Sort recursion count

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, quicksort

What is the minimum number of recursive call to sort a list of n elements using quick sort.
I cannot understand that how many times the recursion function is actually called and specifically what is meant by "minimum number "

Answer (score 3):

Quick Sort is a collection of algorithms where a data set is sorted by choosing a pivot value, partitioning the data and recursing on the partitions until the partition size is smaller than 2.

Simple implementations use the first, last or middle element as pivot and partition the data into 2 sets:

- the elements that compare less or equal to the pivot
- the elements that compare greater or equal to the pivot

Efficient implementations use elaborate methods to choose the pivot value and partition the data into 3 sets:

- the elements that compare less than the pivot
- the elements that compare equal to the pivot
- the elements that compare greater than the pivot

They might also switch to a different algorithm below a certain partition size and or if a pathological distribution is detected, to avoid quadratic time complexity.

For the 3 sets implementations, the optimal cases are those where all elements compare equal and no recursion is needed. This constitutes the *minimum* number of recursive calls: `0`.

In other cases, the number of recursive calls is highly dependent on the data distribution, the pivot selection method and other implementation choices such as:

- base case handling: testing the partition length before recursing or upon entering the function,
- switching to a different algorithm such as insertion sort for small partitions or shell sort for pathological distributions

On average the number of recursive calls for quick sort is approximately:

- **2n** if the length test is only at the start of the function
- **n** if the test is performed before recursing
- **n/t** if switching to another algorithm for partition lengths below a threshold of *t*.

Note that the depth of recursion, which is a different but important question, can be limited to **log<sub>2</sub>(n)** by combining iteration and recursion, recursing on the smaller partition and iterating on the larger one.

Note also that quick sort can be implemented without recursion, using small arrays of length *log<sub>2</sub>(n)* to keep track of pending partitions.

Comment: "...until the partition size is smaller than 2 or some threshold below which a simpler method is more efficient." -- This is a common *optimization* of actual implementations. It is not a necessary part of the Quicksort *algorithm* though.

Comment: @DevSolar: yes, answer amended to distinguish the algorithm description from the implementation choices.